# CentOS : Removed /root

Tags: linux, bash, centos, root

I have been doing experiments with CentOS and now I am in a situation.

I have added an user by mentioning his home directory as `/root` and then I did

```
userdel -rf <username>
```

So its does the job like removing that user & his home directory nothing but `/root` .

Now I dont have `/root` and when I switch to root user using `su - root` its login in as `-bash-4.1#`.

how can I resolve this situation, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With RHEL6 and RHEL7:

```
mkdir /root
chmod 550 /root
cd /etc/skel
cp .bash* /root
```

Comment: Working , thank you. I already created a root directory before posting here . may be bashrc not copied and I think thats stopping it.